# Custom UIMenuController

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, uimenucontroller

Is there a way to add a custom image to the `UIMenuItem` in iOS? It have to look like in Android (Image + Text below). May be there are completed custom controllers? Thx in advance.

Comment: I doubt, but have a look here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIMenuController_Class/UIMenuController.html

Comment: If it was a built-in ability to use the image, I would not ask the question :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can but in a special way — using method swizzling but no any private API. Checkout my project https://github.com/cxa/UIMenuItem-CXAImageSupport for details.